# PHP & SQL - Sum some value from db

Tags: php, sql

I have table like this

```
   A   
======
   2
   7
   7
   8
   9
   3
  ...
   1
======
```

I need to sum all value of row in db, except last value (that is '1'). I know how to sum all value, my question how to sum all value except last value?

```
$sum = 0;
$a = mysql_query('SELECT A FROM tbl');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($a))
{
   $jpos = $row['A'];
   $sum     += intval($jpos);
}
echo $sum;
```

thanks for your response.

Comment: does the last row has highest Id ?

Comment: SQL servers don't guarantee an order unless you specify with ORDER By. How do you know which should be the last line?

Comment: deepak and mike, sory for the mistake, i missed to update the question. i have update it. thanks

Comment: @HerlambangPermadi the update doesnt answer my question..

Comment: Why don't you let MySQL compute the sum for you? I haven't tested it, but something like this should work: `SELECT SUM(A) FROM tbl WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;
$last = 0;
$a = mysql_query('SELECT positif FROM data_aali where id_perusahaan=1');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($a))
{
   $last = intval($row['positif']);
   $sum += $last;
}
$sum -= $last;
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to make an assumption that the table (`tbl`) in question will have at least two columns labelled:

1. id
2. value

This can be done in mysql:

```
SELECT SUM(value)
FROM tbl
WHERE id <> (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl)
```